# Indent all tags following h2 until next h2 is hit using CSS

Tags: html, css, layout, doxygen

In our project I'd like to style our doxygen output differently.
Currently the generated html looks like the following:

```
<html>
<body>
    <h1> Heading 1 </h1>

    <h2> Heading 2.1 </h2>
    <p> Paragraph 2.1.1 </p>
    <p> Paragraph 2.1.2 </p>
    <p> Paragraph 2.1.3 </p>

    <h2> Heading 2.2 </h2>
    <p> Paragraph 2.2.1 </p>
    <p> Paragraph 2.2.2 </p>
    <p> Paragraph 2.2.3 </p>
</body>
</html>
```

The `<h2>` is only styled with a `font-size` attribute and all `<h2>` and `<p>` tags are aligned on the left side of the document.

To let the content below any `<h2>` tag stand out visually I would like to indent the tags until the next `<h2>` tag.

What I tried so far is the following CSS rule:

```
h2 + * {
    margin-left: 10px;
}
```

The `*` is used since there are also other tags present besides `<p>` tags.
However, this rule only indents the first paragraph following the `<h2>` tag and not all tags up to the next `<h2>` tag.

It should also be mentioned that the structure of the html can not be changed to wrap each section inside of a `<div>` for example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like you want to indent all siblings after the first h2 except other h2s, in which case this should do the job:

```
h2 ~ *:not(h2) {
    margin-left: 10px;
}
```

See [the general sibling combinator](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#general-sibling-combinators) and [the negation pseudo-class](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#negation) as well as [a live demo on jsbin](http://jsbin.com/ocozic/1/).

Comment: Works great. Also thanks for the links to the relevant documentation.

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple of options of varying complexity, the first is:

```
h2 ~ *:not(h2) {
    margin-left: 1em;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rz3CD/1/).

This approach selects all following-sibling elements of an `h2` that is not itself an `h2`.

The second is slightly simpler:

```
body {
    padding-left: 1em;
}

body h2 {
    margin-left: -1em;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rz3CD/).

This approach does, essentially, mean that all content except the `h2` will be indented; so it's not quite perfect for your use-case, but may be adaptable to your specific requirements).