# Indent content based on headings

Tags: css

I'm trying to get a style to indent like the following

```
H1
Content here
    H2
    Any content after the H2, paragraphs, images, etc
        H3
        Any content after the H2, paragraphs, images, etc
    H2
    content
H1 another top level heading
etc
```

Sample html:

```
<h1>heading 1</h1>
<p>content</p>
<h2>heading 2</h2>
<p>content</p>
<p>content</p>
<h3>heading 2</h3>
<p>content</p>
<img src="something.png" />
<p>content</p>
<h1>heading 1</h1>
<p>content</p>
```

I've tried the following

```
h2, h2 + * {
    margin-left: 30px;
}

h3, h3 + * {
    margin-left: 60px;
}
```

But this only sets a margin on the first element after the heading, I need all subsequent tags, until the next one.

Any questions please ask.

**I'd like to point out that I can't rewrite the hml as I'm applying this to a website where many pages have already been created.**

Some sample code https://codepen.io/User1972/pen/WZyKNR

Comment: any structure to share ? if nested, padding might do

Comment: please write your real html code

Comment: added some html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS - successive indenting of siblings after headings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31872535/css-successive-indenting-of-siblings-after-headings)

Comment: Hi @Satheesh that is very close but it fails if you have some h2 tags, then another h1 further down the page as the h2 ~ *:not(h1):not(h2) selector is then applied to the tags after the h1 (as they are also after the h1)
Very close though

Comment: Please refer the answer by @caramba (https://stackoverflow.com/a/46690811/5746301)

Comment: @SatheeshKumar this relies on adding to the markup and I can't do this as I'm applying this to lots of existing pages

Comment: In that case, you can give some "class" to the parent of your above given "HTLM" then apply the styles by( @caramba) followed by your "newly added class". Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 6):

I would do this something like this: https://codepen.io/andrasadam93/pen/dVKedR
This way you can easily scale it for further indentations, modify each and every part by adding id's or further classes and get your desired result in later specific cases as well.

```css
.first{
  margin-left:0;
}
.second{
  margin-left:30px;
}
.third{
  margin-left:60px;
}
```

```html
<div class="first">
  <h1>Hello</h1>
  <p>Some content here</p>
  <div class="second">
    <h2>Hello second</h2>
    <p>Also some content here</p>
    <div class="third">
      <h3>Hello third</h3>
      <p>Also some content here</p>
    </div>
    <p>Some further content in the second indentation</p>
  </div>
  <p>This is also some content in the first indentation</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Agreed...a proper HTML structure is the way to go here.

Comment: @Paulie_D does anything speaks against using `<ul><li>` where it scales to infinity without doing anything?

Comment: @caramba This is only personal preference but when it comes to responsive design I rather not use nested lists if possible especially if I am not willing to display plenty of similar data. Technically I do not have anything against lists in this case I was just implying that for further scalability and specific cases this is what I would use especially if the content is not a monotone, large amount of items.

Comment: @caramba if you want to use a list to use its natve padding and build a whole document around it, it is not accurate. dl/dt/dd list could be discussed even that would still be not a proper markup (unless it is is a real list ). HTML on one side - CSS on the other. these are 2 differents jobs ;)

Comment: @caramba Unless this actually **is** a list I'd shy away from non-sematic mark-up and, as @G-Cyr says A `dl` would have the same issues,

Comment: @Paulie_D I get it. For me though it's not clear from the question if it really is a list or not. Also for further scalability I don't see any problems with using lists.

Comment: sorry, I should have said that I can't change the markup. I've added this to the question, and included some sample html

Comment: @user2436996 can you then provide an exact copy with IDs, classes and everything in a codepen?

Answer (score 4):

Why not just use a list `<ul><li>...`

```css
ul, li { list-style: none; }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
      <h1>hello h1</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
      <ul>
        <li>
            <h2>hello h2</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
            <ul>
              <li>
                  <h3>hello h3</h3>
                  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
              </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
      <h1>hello h1</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

or if you do not want to use a list you can achieve the same with one single CSS rule and class like so:

```css
.cheating-list .cheating-list {
    margin-left: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="cheating-list">
  <h1>hello h1</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
  <div class="cheating-list">
    <h2>hello h2</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
      <div class="cheating-list">
        <h3>hello h3</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="cheating-list">
  <h1>hello h1</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
</div>
```

The trick is do add the wrap `<div class="cheating-list">` inside itself.

---

**UPDATED CODE**

**With your sample HTML** (which was added much later) something like this will do the trick (but if possible I would change the markup to one of the above examples)

```css
h1,
h1 ~ *,
h2 ~ h1,
h2 ~ h1 ~ *,
h3 ~ h1,
h3 ~ h1 ~ * {
    margin-left: 0px;
}


h2,
h2 ~ *,
h1 ~ h2,
h1 ~ h2 ~ *:not(h1):not(h3) {
    margin-left: 40px;
}

h3,
h3 ~ *,
h1 ~ h3,
h1 ~ h3 ~ *:not(h1):not(h2) {
    margin-left: 80px;
}
```

```html
<h1>heading 1</h1>
<p>content</p>
<h2>heading 2</h2>
<p>content</p>
<p>content</p>
<h3>heading 3</h3>
<p>content</p>
<img src="something.png" />
<p>content</p>
<h1>heading 1</h1>
<p>content</p>


<h1 class="entry-title">Inputs</h1>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean porttitor, lacus eget egestas pharetra.</p>

<h2><span id="Columns">Columns</span></h2>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean porttitor, lacus eget egestas pharetra.</p>
<ul>
  <li>fghgfdh</li>
  </ul>
<img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x50" />
<h3><span id="another">another heading</span></h3>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean porttitor, lacus eget egestas pharetra.</p>
<h1 class="entry-title">2nd Heading One</h1>
<p>This should not have a margin</p>
<h2><span id="Columns">Columns XXXX</span></h2>
<p>This margin is too large. It has the h3 margin applied to it</p>
<h3><span id="another">another h3 heading</span></h3>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean porttitor, lacus eget egestas pharetra.</p>
```

Comment: you should remove the ul proposal from your answer , it will be easier to upvote for it ;)

Comment: @caramba I've updated my codepen with your suggested css. This works fine on the 2nd h1. But the h2 following the 2nd h1 is not indented. https://codepen.io/User1972/pen/WZyKNR

Comment: @user2436996 update the answer again with code from the codepen

Comment: @caramba thanks for your continued help. If you see the 2nd H1, the content after it still has a left margin applied

Comment: @user2436996 you're welcome and right. but now I give up. It's less work (how much it ever will be) to change the markup. Adding CSS like so is bad practice so better stop it.

Comment: OK - thanks anyway. I would change the markup, but there are hundreds of pages :(

Answer (score 1):

No need for extra classes. For any correctly structured HTML document following CSS is enough:

```
  ul, ol {
    list-style-position: inside;
  } // This is necessary if you use lists. Otherwise just delete this rule.

  h1 ~ *:not(h1) {
    margin-left: 1.2rem;
  }
  h2 ~ *:not(h1, h2) {
    margin-left: 2.4rem;
  }
  h3 ~ *:not(h1, h2, h3) {
    margin-left: 3.6rem;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `margin`, we can achieve this style easily by using **Un-Ordered list.**

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h4 {
  margin: 0px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <h1>H1</h1>
    <p>Content here</p>
    
    <ul>
      <li>
        <h2>H2</h2>
        <p>Any content after the H2, paragraphs, images, etc</p>
         
         <ul>
          <li>
        <h3>H3</h3>
        <p>Any content after the H2, paragraphs, images, etcContent here</p>
           </li>
        </ul>
        
      </li>
      <li>
        <h2>H2</h2>
        <p>Any content after the H2, paragraphs, images, etc</p>
      </li>
      
    </ul>
    
  </li>
  
  <li>
    <h1>H1</h1>
    <p>Content here</p>
    
    <ul>
      <li>
        <h2>H2</h2>
        <p>Any content after the H2, paragraphs, images, etc</p>
         
         <ul>
          <li>
        <h3>H3</h3>
        <p>Any content after the H2, paragraphs, images, etcContent here</p>
           </li>
        </ul>
        
      </li>
      <li>
        <h2>H2</h2>
        <p>Any content after the H2, paragraphs, images, etc</p>
      </li>
      
    </ul>
    
  </li>
</ul>
```

Here I have attached my [codepen link.](https://codepen.io/satheesh_design/pen/JrZvpb)

Comment: This is an amazing answer! Could be from me.

Comment: I have worked in Codepen, That's why I have posted in some delay. After posting only I saw your answer. Upvoted it for your answer.

Comment: It's pleasure to give honor to the answer which is correct and clean :).

Comment: Thanks - this is a good way, but unfortunately I can't amend the markup. I've amended the question to make this clear.