# Indent based on header tag

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have a wordpress site with a structure like this:

### 1.0 Title

Content

#### 1.1 Another title

Content

etc. Nothing special. What I want to do it have everything under each title intent based on the heading tag. So the end output would look like this example:

```
    1.0 TitleName1 
        Paragraph
        Image
        Numbered List      
        1.1 SubTitleName1
            Image
            Paragraph
        1.2 SubTitleName2
            Paragraph
            1.2.1 SubSubTitleName
               Video
    2.0 TitleName2
```

I tried using

```
h2 ~ *:not(h2) {
    margin-left: 25px;
}
```

but that only works when I skip back to another `<h2>` . Is this even possible to achieve without having the users wrap their content in html tags?

Underneath each header there might be a mix of stuff (paragraphs, lists, images etc). Example code:

```html
<h2>1.0 Title</h2>
<p>Stuff and things</p>
<h2>1.1 Another Title</h2>
<p>More stuff</p>
<img>Image.jpeg</img>
<h2> 1.2 Another Title</h2>
<li>bla bla</li>
<h3> 1.2.1 Another title </h3>
<p> more text </p>
<a href=something.html>Link</a>
```

Comment: wrap it in `<ul>` and nest them?

Comment: Oh, I should have mentioned that this is for use in Wordpress and I don't want users to have to add any html tags.

Comment: they have access to a rich-text editor then ... they just need to click the bullet points with numbers next to it ... ?

Comment: I've edited my question again and added more examples of what might be included under each heading to clarify even more (sorry, I'm still learning how to submit clear questions hehe)

Comment: all contents are in h2 tag or p tag? Please provide your HTML code.

Comment: @Sarbaz the content can be of any type, But I only want the <h2>,<h3>,<h4> and <h5> to control the intendation level of the content. I hope that makes sense

Comment: The markup does not match the outline given above. If 1.1 should be further indented, it has to be an H3, not an H2 for example.

Answer (score 0):

I found the exact same question already answered:

[CSS - successive indenting of siblings after headings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31872535/css-successive-indenting-of-siblings-after-headings)

```html
h2 ~ *:not(h1):not(h2) {
  margin-left: 2em;
}
h3 ~ *:not(h1):not(h2):not(.h2):not(h3) {
  margin-left: 3em;
}
h4 ~ *:not(h1):not(h2):not(.h2):not(h3):not(.h3):not(h4) {
  margin-left: 4em;
}
```